# Eigenvectors of "weighted" Hermitian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Consider two *real* matrices $\boldsymbol{H}$ and $\boldsymbol{D}$ with the following properties:

- $\boldsymbol{H}$ is a symmetric matrix (since it is a real matrix this is equivalent to being Hermitian).
- $\boldsymbol{H}$ is *strictly positive definite* (all eigenvalues are strictly greater than zero).
- $\boldsymbol{D}$ is a diagonal matrix with *strictly positive* diagonal entries.

**Question:** I am trying to find out whether there exists a closed form expression for the eigenvectors of $\boldsymbol{DHD}$ in terms of the eigenvectors and/or eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{H}$. (Just to clarify: I am *not* interested in the matrix $\boldsymbol{DHD}^{-1}$.)

**Comment:** the matrix $\boldsymbol{H}$ is real symmetric and therefore it is diagonalizable so that there exists a matrix $\boldsymbol{S}$ with $\boldsymbol{H}=\boldsymbol{S\Lambda S}^{-1}$ for some diagonal matrix $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$. The eigenvectors of $\boldsymbol{H}$ are therefore simply the columns of $\boldsymbol{S}$. Next, the matrix $\boldsymbol{DHD}$ is also diagonalizable (since it is also real symmetric) so that $\boldsymbol{DHD}=\boldsymbol{S_2\Lambda_2 S_2}^{-1}$. I was wondering if it is possible to relate $\boldsymbol{S}$ to $\boldsymbol{S}_2$ via some closed form expression.

---

**Update**

The simplified explanation of the reason I am interested in this problem is as follows:

I have a vector $f(\boldsymbol{S})\boldsymbol{\mu}$ which is the mean of a random variable ($f(\cdot)$ is a known function) while a separate random variable has mean $f_2(\boldsymbol{S_2})\boldsymbol{\mu}$ ($f_2(\cdot)$ is another known function). Right now, I am looking for the ideal situation in which I can express one in terms of the other so that someone who knows $\boldsymbol{D}$, $\boldsymbol{S}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ can **easily** infer $\boldsymbol{S_2}$. Additionally, I'm also searching for expressions on how the individual entries of the two mean vectors relate to each other (I would like to look at the entry-wise ratios of the two mean vectors). (This may be too hopeful.)

Indeed, there may be an easier way to tackle my original problem due to probabilistic properties which I've omitted for simplicity. However, I think a question including the entire problem would lack specificity; this is simply one of the current approaches I'm pursuing.

Comment: I very much doubt there is a useful closed form expression. However, there are almost certainly relevant inequalities. You might want to check Bhatia's Matrix Analysis

Comment: Thanks for your input! This is my fear too but I haven't thought about it long enough to give up!

Comment: It might be helpful if you say something about what you're trying to accomplish with such a closed form expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can't be a closed form expression here (for any meaning of "closed form" that is weaker than roots of sextic polynomials).  For example, try

$$ H = \pmatrix{3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr
            1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
            0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr
            0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 0\cr
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 1\cr
            1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3\cr},\ 
    D = \text{diag}(1,2,3,4,5,6)$$

Then the nice Toeplitz matrix $H$ has eigenvalues $1,2,2,4,4,5$, with nice eigenvectors having entries of $\pm 1$ and $0$.  But $D H D$ has characteristic polynomial $${\lambda}^{6}-273\,{\lambda}^{5}+25507\,{\lambda}^{4}-1015971\,{
\lambda}^{3}+17394856\,{\lambda}^{2}-111331584\,\lambda+165888000
$$ 
which is irreducible over the rationals and has Galois group $S_6$, thus its roots can't be expressed in radicals.  Of course the eigenvalues can be obtained from the eigenvectors.  So somehow your "closed form" will have to be able to take integer inputs and come up with the roots of an unsolvable sextic polynomial.

Comment: Excellent insight, thanks!